# Book identification: 90s/2000s novel, American travels to fictional town called Khartoum

Tags: story-identification, books

looking for help identifying a book I read in the mid 2000's.

Main character receives strange email about seeing the end of the world in Khartoum - a fictional place rather than the actual city I believe.

He goes, and stays there. Supporting characters include an Irish(?) soldier who was fighting with the UN, and a Russian lieutenant who was against them. They ended up staying in the town.

There was a hotel, frequented by a senile lady. Her senility was a plot point early.

The native population are nurturing sacs of liquid it turns out, which turn out to be living supply crates for when an alien ship lands to take them off planet (I think.)

Ends with the Russian lieutenant being voted out of the shelter the surviving expats were in during a firefight with the natives. Main character leaves to find him and book ends there.

Comment: Not quite the same, but reminded me of this (unsolved) book search on goodreads: https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/17484360-young-adult-novel-from-late-90s-mid-2000s-set-in-khartoum-khantoum-fea

Comment: and there's also this one: https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/19601521-weird-adult-fiction-book-set-in-central-asian-middle-eastern-city--lot-o

Answer (score 2):

It's Eclipse of the Century by Jan Marks - it was found on this reddit thread xxx

https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/9vi2cq/weird_adult_fiction_book_set_in_central/elsgijy/?context=3

Comment: This is a nice find but could you perhaps [edit] in some relevant information from the link in case it dies and add some information about the work for how it matches the OP's description?